# Randomly lost folder permissions

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-permissions

I found that many subfolders in my shared folder lost all their permission. I cannot understand why and I did not find something relevent in event logs. I also cannot understand which folder are affected, seems to be a random selection.

I had to take ownership of all files then replace them from the parent folder *(replace all child object permissions with inharitable permissin from this object)*.

This is a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine with only shared folder service, there is a daily machine backup with Veeam and the shadow volume copy is enabled.

It never happened to any of you? What can be?

Answer (score 0):

Random issue is pretty difficult to troubleshoot. May I ask when the problem happens, is there any new updates/changes for your server?
For example: windows system updates? Installed the 3rd party softwares?
And does this happen in specific time?

In addition, here are a few things I suggest you could check:
•Find out whether there is any script running which modifies folder permissions.
•Group Policy can also customize specific folder permissions.
•Try to disable any third party software installed to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you Mary Dong, I know this is very general question but I'm groping in the dark. I will check what you said.